# Ffmpeg transcoding video .vob (vcodec MPEG-2)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, transcode, vob, mpeg2

I want to transcode a file .vob to get the bitrate 1500 with 16/9 ratio I execute this command ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i /path/video.vob -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2 -strict experimental -b:v 1308k -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -r 25 /path/video_1500.mp4 2>&1
```

But I got a video with size: 1280 x 1024. What options I should add to my command ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Your source video looks to be PAL 720x576, based on the input format and scaler's output size.

If so, you'll have to pad the video to get a 16:9 frame size. Use

```
ffmpeg -i /path/video.vob -r 25 -vf "scale=960:720,setsar=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1308k -b:a 192k -ar 44100 -strict -2  /path/video_1500.mp4 2>&1
```

If your ffmpeg is from 2016 or later, you can drop `-strict -2`.